# Edit IEEEtran layout file

Tags: lyx, ieeetran

I'm using the IEEE transaction class with lyx (IEEEtran layout)
and I need to define this options

```
[12pt, draftclsnofoot, onecolumn]
```

When I'm using this line in the custom layout settings only the font size changes and the document is still two columns.

In the IEEEtran.layout there is only one option:

> ClassOptions
>
> FontSize    9|10|11|12
>
> end

How can I add the `onecolumn` and the `draftclsnofoot` options to the layout file?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=27302&view=unread#unread)

Answer (score 1):

Go to <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings ...</kbd> > <kbd>Document class</kbd> > <kbd>Custom</kbd> and just write the options delimited by commas:  `12pt, draftclsnofoot, onecolumn`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, That is exactly what i did and still the paper is in two columns :(

Comment: @user102890 what does your View>Source>Preamble Only say? How about Document>Settings>Text Layout?

Comment: @user102890 Are you using in addition the geometry package? or multicol package? or minipages?  or a table? or ...  Without knowing more of your document we can only guess.  This example work well in one column, so  my suggestion is that you should start with this minimal example (of course without  the `\usepackage{lipsum}`  nor `\lipsum[1-8]`) and then reconstruct step by step you original file, starting with the LaTeX preamble, checking in every step that you are not doing something wrong.